# NodeJS-MySQL scopes

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
  con.query(
          `SELECT user.*  FROM user WHERE (deactivated_status= "" OR deactivated_status="False") AND user.id NOT IN (SELECT blocked_id from blocked_users WHERE userID="${result[0].id}") AND  user.id NOT IN (SELECT userID from blocked_users WHERE blocked_id="${result[0].id}") AND age BETWEEN '${preference_result[0].ageFrom}' AND '${preference_result[0].ageTo}'  AND gender='${gender}' AND   user.country IN (${array})`,
          
          function (err, results, fields) {
            if (err) {
              res.send("Fail");
              throw err;
            }
            var i=0;
        
            if(results.length>0){
                for( i=0;i<results.length;i++){
           
            
                con.query(
                  `SELECT payment_status  FROM payment WHERE userID='${result[0].id}' AND paid_to_id='${user.id}' `,
                  function(err,result_paid,fields){
                    if(err){
                    res.send("Error");
                    return;
                  }
                  **** Code to be corrected here*** 
                   results[i].payment_status=result_paid.payment_status
                })
              
                }
             }
        //  console.log(results)
           
            res.json({'results':results})
          }
        ); 
      }
      
      );
      }
    })}
    catch(e){
      res.send('Error Fetching Matching Profiles.')
  
      
    }
});

});
```

So I have an sql query in the first part which gets a list of users, I then run a for loop on the first sql result list and call query on each user [i] retrieved from the first query and append a property called payment status which is the result of the second query on that particular index. However, the final result outside the mysql query functions is not being registered and no property is being appended nor can I access the index in the second query. I am guessing it has something to do with callbacks not setting the values. Kindly help me out on how I can append the property with the value of the first query , Thanks!

Comment: Please dont use callback versions of MySQL, if your using mysql from NPM it's not been updated for over 4 years anyway.   Try -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2  This version has Promises built in and is actively maintained.   After doing that you can then use `async / await` and that will make things much easier.

Comment: try with set resultsArray to outer scope of all program and updating in the inner callback. or try with let in for loop like for( let i=0;i<results.length;i++){